# Return value from input dialog, android

Tags: android

everyone.

I'm making an android project for my school and I have few questions.

I don't have too much experience in developing android applications.

So, let me explain what I want to do:

I want the user to put some integers, and then when he presses button named "calculate",  my app calculates an equation that I have in my code.

The tricky part that I haven't been able to make it work is to pop-up an input dialog(everything ok until here) and the number he enter appear in the main activity...In the main activity I want to replace the text of a button or a textview..

Comment: Hello Takis, and welcome to StackOverflow. To better help us understand your question, please post the code with which you are having your issue.

Comment: `the number he texts appear in the main activity...At the main activity i want to replace the text of a button or a textview..` So, you already got the number and have in your main Activity. You have all you need, so what is the question about?

Comment: The question is, how can i get the number from the input dialog to the main activity.

Comment: its pretty easy. plz post the code of your main activity and dialog so that i can help u further

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code:

I have run it to my phone for testing and the dialog appears, but if i click ok it crashes.
Sorry but this is my first attempt on creating an android application.

Main Activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test1.justtesting.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/schematic"
        android:src="@drawable/schematic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonu1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Buttonu1"
        android:onClick="showprompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonr2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonr1"
        android:text="@string/Buttonr2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:onClick="calculate"
        android:text="@string/Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonr1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/Buttonr1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mathtype"
        android:src="@drawable/mathtype" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonu2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonu1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/Buttonu2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Main Activity.java

```
package com.test1.justtesting;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final Context context = this;
    private EditText result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


   public void showprompt (View view) {

                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);


                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);


                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // get user input and set it to result
                            // edit text
                            result.setText(userInput.getText());
                            }
                          })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            }
                          });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
```

Comment: Ok guys, I‘ll try it and i let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 result.setText(userInput.getText());
```

leads to the crash as the variable "result" is null. Android does not know what you want to change. Add

```
 result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.something);
```

in your oncreate method. Note you must do it after you set contentview. You should learn how to read your console for debug.

Happy learning Android!

Answer (score 0):

The error is here :

```
result.setText(userInput.getText());
```

You got text from userInput edittext field. But you can't set a text to an edittext. You have to set a string. So, you have to get a string from userInput. The simple solution is

```
result.setText(userInput.getText().toString());
```